# Preserving paper stickers long term

Tags: paper, preservation, framing

I'm going to frame a few old video game cartridges in a box frame for art and preservation.

I got the idea from a few posts I've seen online of others who have done the same:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm going use a sheet of foam and cut out the squares for the cartridges to sit in, within the box frame.

My one concern is the paper sticker-labels on the cartridges fading over time. They will be behind the glass frame permanently, but I don't want them to fade due to light exposure. My only idea so far for maintaining the labels is to not hang the frame in a location that will ever be exposed to direct sunlight. My only other thought is perhaps using special glass on the frame which reduces the light damage on the art inside? But I'm not sure if this even exists?

**Is there anything else I can do to extend the lifespan of these cartridge labels?**

Links to original posts:

https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/csgqfp/

https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/85k9d0/

https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/72kkut/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The greatest culprit of the fading of printed colour is UV light. This process is called photo-degradation.

You can protect your images by framing them using **conservation glass** or **UV filtering Plexiglas** (which can be found at most art supply stores and framing ateliers), or coat the glass you already have with **UV protective spray**. This process needs to be repeated, though. There are also (adhesive) protective sheets you can cut to size, either to cover the frame window or the individual objects, but these are harder to find.

Apart from hanging your pictures **out of direct sunlight**, be sure to **frame them cleanly, and place them in a stable and dry environment, away from heat sources**.

Comment: I hadn't heard of "conservation glass" before, so this is definitely what I'll be looking to implement. Thank you!